# I want to change href of anhor tag on all subpages except homepage or main page of website using Javascript or any other method

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

Hello guys this must be very simple but I am not able to figure it out.

> I want href in  some nav links that are in dropdown   to change when the user navigates to any subpages of website and remain same when the user is on the homepage  for example

when a user is on homepage ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) href should be

> href="#div_id1"

and when the user goes to subpage e.g.=www.example.com/contactpage then

> href="www.example.com#div_id1"

I am using   dynamic header so can't use different navbar code on other page

below is my code

```html
<li id="dropdownheading" class="nav-item   my-auto dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle " href="#" id="navbarDropdown" 
                     role="button" ata-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown heading
  </a>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu " aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#div-id1">div 1</a></li>    
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#div-id2">div 2</a></li>    
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#div-id2">div 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Try href="./#div_id1" in both pages. Also, the id after the hashtag is different from the one you have in your HTML anchor tag.

Comment: not `./#` but `/#` so it points to root always.

Comment: Thanks a ton, @NeilLu I had no idea it could be so simple thanks